# List size is zero even after adding items

Tags: java, android, arrays, list

I have a list that I sending to a background asynctask object to do somework on. I am also sending a custom list adapter to be able to populate my list in the background. But the list returns zero and it seems like nothing is added to it as its size remains zero. I know because i debuged it. my custom list adapter works just fine though and creates the list perfectly.

Here's my code.

**Fragment_Events.java**

```
public class Fragment_Events extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

    FragmentController controller;

    ListView eventsListView;
    List<Event> events;
    EventsListAdapter eventsListAdapter;

    public Fragment_Events() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        controller = (FragmentController) getActivity();
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        eventsListView = (ListView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.listView_events);
        events = new ArrayList<Event>();//SIZE REMAINS 0 <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
        eventsListAdapter = new EventsListAdapter(getActivity(),R.layout.list_events,events);
        eventsListView.setAdapter(eventsListAdapter);

        DLEvents.init(events,eventsListAdapter);
        Bundle sendingBundle = new Bundle();
        ArrayList<String> eventNames = new ArrayList<String>();


        sendingBundle.putStringArrayList(AppUtils.EVENT_NAMES,eventNames);
        controller.sendData(sendingBundle);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_events, container, false);
    }


    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

    }
}
```

**DLEvents.java**

```
public class DLEvents {

    public static final String EVENTS_OBJECT = "Events";
    public static final String NAME_COLUMN = "name";
    public static final String DESC_COLUMN = "description";
    public static final String DATE_COLUMN = "date";
    public static final String FOLL_COLUMN = "followers";
    public static final String TC_COLUMN = "ticketCount";
    public static final String IMAGE_COLUMN = "image";

    public static void init(List<Event> list,EventsListAdapter eventsListAdapter){

        DownLoadData downLoadData = new DownLoadData(list,eventsListAdapter);
        downLoadData.execute();
    }


    public static class DownLoadData extends AsyncTask<Void,Event,Void>{

        public List<Event>events;
        public EventsListAdapter eventsListAdapter;

        public DownLoadData(List<Event>events, EventsListAdapter eventsListAdapter) {

            super();
            this.events = events;
            this.eventsListAdapter = eventsListAdapter;

        }



        public Bitmap byteArrayToBitmap(byte[] bytes){
            Bitmap temp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
            return temp;
        }


        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery(EVENTS_OBJECT);
            try {
                for(ParseObject tempParseObject: query.find()){
                    String tempName = tempParseObject.getString(NAME_COLUMN);
                    String tempDesc = tempParseObject.getString(DESC_COLUMN);
                    String tempID  = tempParseObject.getObjectId();
                    int tempTC = tempParseObject.getInt(TC_COLUMN);
                    ParseFile tempPF = (ParseFile)tempParseObject.get(IMAGE_COLUMN);

                    Bitmap tempBM = byteArrayToBitmap(tempPF.getData());
                    int tempFoll = tempParseObject.getInt(FOLL_COLUMN);
                    Event event = new Event(tempName,tempDesc,null,tempID,tempTC,tempBM,tempFoll);
                    publishProgress(event);
                }
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Event... values) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
            //events.add(values[0]); //I commented it out because it causes my listview to have duplicates, if you can shed some light on this too , I'd appreciate it. Commenting it back in also doesn't affect the size of my list
            eventsListAdapter.add(values[0]);

        }
    }

}
```

Asynctask seems to be working fine as the list is populated with no issues. but the list is still at a size 0 event though it's updated in the UI thread via onprogressreport

the adapter populates the list perfectly! that isn't the issue. The event's list that is being passed on to asynctask remains at a zero size. No item is being added. That is the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You have to call `notifyDataSetChanged()` to update the adapter and let it know there is new data.

```
@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Event... values) {
    super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    //events.add(values[0]); //I commented it out because it causes my listview to have duplicates, if you can shed some light on this too , I'd appreciate it. Commenting it back in also doesn't affect the size of my list
    eventsListAdapter.add(values[0]);
    eventsListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: As i said the adapter works. The list is populated with no issues. It's the events list that stays at a zero size

Answer (score 0):

You need to ask adapter to refresh itself once data is available or its data is modified.

Do this

```
@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Event... values) {
    super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    events.add(values[0]); 
    eventsListAdapter.add(values[0]);
    eventsListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```